# How to import the data (list of URLs) from a CSV instead of use an search string? Thank you a lot

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

I´m so newbie in Python and I need to unite the first and second code cause I want to read the data (phones and ZIPs) from a a list of URLs store in a CSV. I tried a lot.

This code is from Python 360 on YouTube:

```
    # read csv with just url per line
    with open('urls.csv') as file:
        start_urls = [line.strip() for line in file]
    
    def start_request(self):
        request = Request(url = self.start_urls, callback=self.parse)
        yield request
    
    def parse(self, response):
    
            html = response.body
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
            text = soup.get_text()
```

Ans this from nageshsinghc4 (GitHub) :)

```
...

    for row in df2.iterrows():  # Parse through each url in the list.
        try:
            try:
               req1 = Request(row[1]['URL'], headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.75 Safari/537.36'})
               gcontext = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23) # Bypass SSL certification verification
               f = urlopen(req1, context=gcontext)
               url_name = f.geturl() #extract URL name 
               s = f.read()
               phone = re.findall(r"((?:\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))?(?:\s|-|\.)?\d{3}(?:\s|-|\.)\d{4})",s)  # Phone regex
               emails = re.findall(r"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,3}",s)  #Email regex
    
               if len(phone) == 0:
                  print("No phone number found.")
                  err_msg_phn = "No phone number found."
                  phn_1.append((url_name, err_msg_phn))
                  
               else:
                   count = 1
                   for item in phone:
                       phn_1.append((url_name,item))
                       count += 1
                   print(phn_1)
            
               if len(emails) == 0:
                  print("No email address found.")
                  err_msg_mail = "No email address found."
                  mail_1.append((url_name,err_msg_mail))
    
               else:
                   count = 1
                   for item in emails:
                       mail_1.append((url_name,item))
                       count += 1
                   print(mail_1)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: in first code you get HTML in `html` (`html = response.body`) and in second code you get HTML in `s` (`s = r.read()`). So maybe you should copy second code to `parse()` and use `s = response.body`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @furas. What do you do with this?              
req1 = Request(row[1]['URL'], headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.75 Safari/537.36'})
           gcontext = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23) # Bypass SSL certification verification
           f = urlopen(req1, context=gcontext)
           url_name = f.geturl() #extract URL name

Comment: remove it - you don't need it. I assumed that you use full code from `Python 360 on YouTube` - and it uses module `scrapy` which runs requests automatically and gives you HTML, so you don't have to run request manually